# Binding AAR with Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, dll, binding, aar

I am trying to bind an AAR file with xamarin following this example.

[Binding an AAR](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/)

When I try to actually build the dll I get several of these errors.

```
.../obj/Debug/generated/src/Org.Apache.Commons.Lang3.StringUtils.cs(68,68): Error CS0231: A params parameter must be the last parameter in a formal parameter list (CS0231) (TeladocAarBinding)

Identifier Expected (CS1001)

Syntax error, ',' expected (CS1003)
```

I am new to doing this, so I really don't have a clue. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: *Usually* you can remove the org.apache.commons.* classes from your bindings, consult JonD's Xamarin Android Bindings Troubleshooting guide : https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb

Comment: Ok, that seems to have solved the issue with apache. Now I've got 343 errors linked to Com.Bumptech.Glide.* missing, or something

Comment: If the library that you are binding uses Glide, you will need to add it to your binding library

Comment: Is there a way to add the whole library and not just specific classes?

Comment: ?....In adding AAR or Jars you are adding the "whole library"....

Comment: Sorry, I am really new to this binding thing. Can I just include the jar in a binding project?